# How to set focus on FormControl - Select? (react)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have [material-ui - select](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/selects/) and would like to programmatically focus on this element.

```
<FormControl 
className="select100">
<Select
    ref={(formControll) => { this.formControll = formControll; }}                                 
    native
    value={value}
    input={<Input id="integer" />}
>
    {possibleOptions.map((item, key) => {
      return (<option value={item} key={key}>{item}</option>)
    })}
</Select>
```

I tried with the `ref` and write `this.formControll.focus()`; but react is telling me that focus() is not a function. With a button for example the ref is working.

PS: I don't need `autoFocus`

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the `Input` inside the `Select` the `autoFocus` prop and this will apply to the `Select`.

```
<Select
  native
  value={value}
  input={<Input id="integer" autoFocus={true} />}
>
  {possibleOptions.map((item, key) => {
    return (<option value={item} key={key}>{item}</option>)
  })}
</Select>
```

**Edit**
When i posted the answer i have missed the part that you don't need the `autoFocus`.

If you are using an input inside your `Select` then you can use the `inputRef` prop and this will focus the underline input "attached" to the select.
[Code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/910vjx4vx4) and [Docs.](https://material-ui-next.com/guides/api/#internal-components)

Comment: As I said in my initial post. I don't need autoFocus, because autoFocus only works on site load. After that autoFocus isn't working anymore.

I have read that **inputRef** should work. At least **this.formControll.focus()** isn`t throwhing an error anymore. focus() is a working method, but still it isn't focusing :-(

Comment: Yeah `inputRef` will not throw an error because its a valid prop on the `Input` api. Though i think its not the actual element you want to focus, you need the select to be focused, but they didn't expose a prop for the ref of the select.

Comment: You are telling me only that it is not working. What is working to programmatically set the focus of a select field? x)

Comment: yeah i miss read your comment. `inputRef` should work if you are passing an `Input` to `Select`. i've updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
<Select
    ref="selectRef"                                 
    native
    value={value}
    input={<Input id="integer" />}
>
    {possibleOptions.map((item, key) => {
      return (<option value={item} key={key}>{item}</option>)
    })}
</Select>
```

To access, use

```
this.refs.selectRef.focus()
```

Here's a reference [github link](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/1594)